# DecodeJpeg / Content: 0 'refers to a tensor that does not exist

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

After retraining my model on tensorflow by following method in the tutorial video by Siraj Raval 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8

I encountered the below error when i finally tested my test image but it generated two errors as seen in screenshot
[image]

There are two errors ,a Type and a Key error and both of their root cause is probably DecodeJpeg/Contents: 0 
If anyone can explain me the errors and give its resolution then it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

DecodeJpeg/Contents:0 is supposed to be a tensor, and you want to feed data to it, so you consider it as an input. Problem is that it doesn't exist, this probably means that you made a small mistake in the naming.
run this before the sess.run(something, {"DecodeJpeg/Contents:0": something})

```
tf.summary.FileWriter("name_of_a_folder", sess.graph)
```

this will generate a log file in that folder. then run in cli:

```
tensorboard --log_dir /name/to/that/folder/
```

and open your browser on the link provided in the cli, now you can see the graph and check the real name of the tensor. If you still have problems, feel free to share the graph image, or ask away.